# Google calendar events missing seemingly at random

Tags: samsung, calendar, google-calendar

Some events I've created show up and some don't on the same calendar across different accounts.

I've tried checking and unchecking them.

I've tried turning them off and on in the Android settings.

I've tried the `Sync now` button.

They show up in my Google Calendar web view and in Fantastical on my Mac.

It's only on my phone that they seem to not show up it's very inconsistent which do or don't show. I can see some events appear and others don't show up at all, then mysteriously show up sometimes way past the event.

This also happens with groups. I was recently invited to a group. It took several days for it to even show up on the side bar and when it finally did show, none of the events became visible on my Android calendar but did everywhere else. The group is checked as visible in the sidebar.

This is causing me to miss invites and now I have to regularly check the web copy just to make sure I'm not missing something.

How can I fix this?

Using a Samsung Galaxy S22 with Android version 13 build #TP1A.220624.014.S908U1UES2CWCC.

Comment: If all data is OK just not on your phone a local problem is very likely. May be the used database that is synchronized with the cloud is corrupt. The only way that comes to may mind is cleaning some app data (but I am not sure which apps may be appropriate in your case) and remove and re-add your Google account.

Comment: Was concerned I'd have to do that. I have a lot of accounts, so removing and recreating them could cause issues. Hoping to find an alternative solution.

Comment: @Robert I tried removing a test account, but when I added it back, it doesn't show up in the Calendar app at all. Going to "Manage Accounts" in Calendar shows it is missing. The Google account settings show that calendar syncing is turned on.